# Where to download 10m (1/3 arc-second) DEMs?

Tags: dem, united-states, data

I'm looking for some of the 10m DEM to fill in the white Quad areas. Do you know where of can I find them?  These 10 DEMs we have are actually coming from the NRCS Geospatial Dataway. I believe they were not available yet. Are there some web sites that allow me to download some of the DEM ?[image: Here is the screenshot]

What I want is to find them in 10m. I have check out the USGS National Viewer Map and they have 1,2,3 arc seconds.

**Place** = Mount Baldy (aka Baldy Mountain), which is located on Cimarron Range of the Sangre de Cristo mountains of southern U.S.'s New Mexico state.

Comment: One of the quads is Mount Baldy (aka Mount San Antonio), so San Gabriel mountains of southern California.

Comment: No, it is Southern New Mexico. Right next to south of us is Mexico. To the left, is Arizona. Sorry for not providing a clear description of where...

Comment: Andre Silva, which question are you talking about ? The title of it or my description in looking for a website ?

Comment: Probert: comments that ask for more information usually indicate that you should put that information into the question, not into a follow-on comment. It is easier to understand the situation if all the detail in one place. It also avoids the "chat in comments" issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download NED datasets through the [National Map Viewer](http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/viewer/).  The screenshot shows the availability of ~3m (1/9 arc second) and 10m (1/3 arc second) resolution NED datasets throughout the USA.  According to this map, you should have excellent 10m coverage for your New Mexico locations.  To the right of the screenshot, you can see the helpful download options.

To confirm that these datasets are indeed available, I downloaded a 1/3 arcsecond DEM of the Lang Canyon quad from your screenshot.  The download was successful in GridFloat format, so you should be good to go.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Aaron, I understand it now. Don't know why USGS use that word 1/3 arc second. I would much rather use the word 10m DEM instead of that odd word ! They need to live up to current properly words.

Comment: Aaron, Thanks for showing me the Title you edit. Now I know more for next time. Sorry I was not explaining very clearly.

Comment: The elevation data are not projected - they are distributed in geographic at a 1/3 arc-second resolution. So they are not 10m DEMs (though the source may have been).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is the [New Mexico Resource Geographic Information System](http://rgis.unm.edu/browsedata#) (RGIS) which lists some 'enhanced' 10m DEMs for the area you're interested in.

Comment: mkennedy, thanks. I have gone into that website and found that theirs DEM is old for some of the quad I need. They are 2002 compared to USGS National Viewer Map and they have in 2009. Would the years matter ? My thought maybe there might be some changes since 2002 ?

Comment: Unless you specifically looking at change over time or another historical analysis, you definitely should use the most recent data! One of the quads I checked the metadata on listed 2005 as the acquisition date.